# Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly - after maven installation

Tags: 12.04, installation, java, environment-variables, maven-3

I installed Java JDK on Ubuntu 12.04 and added Java home to my path at `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/opt/jdk1.7.0_40/jdk1.7.0_40/bin:$PATH
```

This looks a little bit strange but it's really my path.

After this I installed maven through:

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

It installed all the needed libraries and now when I run `mvn -version`, I see:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.  
We cannot execute /opt/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java
```

What is wrong with it?

- ***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: @minerz029 I first time here about this things. Can you explain more about this things? How do really to write this variable? Can you show one at this example?

Comment: try sudo ./mkdistro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add these lines to your `~/.pam_environment` file instead (create it if it doesn't exist)

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/opt/jdk1.7.0_40/jdk1.7.0_40/bin
JAVA_HOME DEFAULT=/opt/jdk1.7.0_40/jdk1.7.0_40
```

[More information (read this)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables)

Using `.bashrc` is not recommended at the above link.

Answer (score 0):

add to your .bashrc this command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_40/jdk1.7.0_40
```

Comment: Perfect I did this and my output is `Apache Maven 3.0.4 ...`. Why was this happen?

Comment: because most of java based applicatons need this variable to know the java path

Answer (score 0):

Had same error message and after install of debian 1.6 jdk the file in
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java was a symbolic link to ../jre/bin/java,
which was not set executable, fixed with:

```
chmod 755 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/../jre/bin/java
```

and without changing JAVA_HOME, or anything else, it worked.